# Parity Substrate - blocks are not being finalized

Tags: substrate

## Problem

I am running a private chain with 2 local nodes using custom accounts and keys.

Peer discovery works, but blocks are not being finalized.

```
Idle (1 peers), best: #0 (0xb166…8ad2), finalized #0 (0xb166…8ad2),
Idle (1 peers), best: #0 (0xb166…8ad2), finalized #0 (0xb166…8ad2),
...
```

## Description

In `chain_spec.rs`:

- Create a new set of accounts from *Armstrong, Armstrong//stash,
  Aldrin, Aldrin//stash* seeds the way it is done in the bin/node :

  `AccountPublic::from(sp_core::Public::Pair::from_string(seed)).into_account()`
- Set the initial authorities to the controller accounts *Armstrong* and *Aldrin*.
- Create the `SessionKeys` for the initial authorities.
- `BalancesConfig`: endow some balances for each account.
- `SessionConfig`: use the `SessionKeys` I just created.
- `StakingConfig`: set the `stakers` as a 4-tuple containing `(stash, controlller, amount, StakerStatus::Validator)`

This results in a build-spec like:

**palletSession**

```
{
    "keys": [
        [
        "<STASH_ID>",
        {
            "grandpa": "...",
            "babe": "<CONTROLLER_ID>",
            "im_online": "<CONTROLLER_ID>",
            "authority_discovery": "<CONTROLLER_ID>"
        }
        ],
        [
        "<STASH_ID>",
        {
            "grandpa": "...",
            "babe": "<CONTROLLER_ID>",
            "im_online": "<CONTROLLER_ID>",
            "authority_discovery": "<CONTROLLER_ID>"
        }
        ]
    ]
}
```

**palletStaking**

```
"stakers": [
    [
        "<STASH_ID>",
        "<CONTROLLER_ID>",
        <STASH_AMOUNT>,
        "Validator"
    ],
    [
        "<STASH_ID>",
        "<CONTROLLER_ID>",
        <STASH_AMOUNT>,
        "Validator"
    ]
]
```

## Polkadot.js UI

- Peer is shown in the Explorer -> Node info:

[image]

- I can add the created accounts to the Address Book, but they are not showing in Accounts:

[image]
[image]

- Stash accounts show up in the Stacking screen as validators, but Account actions shows a `No funds staked yet. Bond funds to validate or nominate a validator` message:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This might be a basic question but we've seen it some many times before: Are you running a release build? running debug is most often too slow to produce and finalize anything.

Comment: @kianenigma Thank you for your answer, I am indeed running a release build. It is worth mentioning that I am able to produce / finalize blocks once I do a `author_insertKey` rpc and restart both nodes (using the public keys for `babe` and `grandpa` provided by the `subkey` command). However, isn't setting the `SessionKeys` for `pallet_session` on genesis enough? That is how it is done for Alice and Bob and works out of the box.

Comment: Hey @TMichel, can you please support our Substrate StackExchange proposal: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Answer (score 1):

1. check, that you've added grandpa private keys to the node's storage (author_insertKey, or rotate). When you start alice/bob chain private keys are already in storage
2. there is an issue that node is checking that private keys are in storage at start (spawning grandpa thread), so if you insert grandpa private keys you need to restart the node.